# `View` blur possible like `Image`?

Tags: react-native

In React Native I can blur an `Image` with `blurRadius={30}`, what is the equivalent for a `View` component? I would like the edges to be blurred as well, not just the contents.

Comment: Add `Image` in `View` with `position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, zIndex: 1` then add your contents behind that `Image`. Will this work for you?